# Change many-to-one domain based on selection field

Tags: odoo

I want to change the domain of many-to-one field based on user selection, selection field have to options (code, phone), but the domain does not change and get only the default value:

```
    @api.onchange('search_by')
    def _get_partner(self):
        partners  = self.env['customer.regist'].search([('name','!=','New')])
        partner_list = []
        partner_list2 = []
        for rec in partners:
            partner_list.append(rec.name)
            partner_list2.append(rec.phone)
        res = {}
        if self.search_by == 'code':
            res['domain'] = {'search_value': [('name', 'in', partner_list)]}
        if self.search_by == 'phone':
            res['domain'] = {'search_value': [('phone', 'in', partner_list2)]}
        return res
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain in more detail what you want to accomplish so I can give you a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the code but from the look of it the domain will always contain all customer.regist records (except the ones with the name 'New' of course). You are going through all the records and adding their phones / names to a list and then say that the phone / name must be included in that list. So you will always have all of them.